# finder like swing component

Tags: swing, user-interface, graphics, paint, jtree

Does anyone have suggestions how to implement a widget similar to mac's finder in swing?

Things were done in javascript like [here](http://christianyates.com/blog/jquery/finder-column-view-hierarchical-lists-jquery)

I just wonder if it's possible by extending JTree and overwriting paint method?

I don't need a file browser I'm after horizontally expanding menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks more like a set of `JList`s next to each other, where the contents of the `JList` in container x+1 is determined by the selection of the `JList` in container x . I would not bother with a `JTree`